# Save file under predefined name

Tags: php, http, download

I created a File-Download Script that works quite well. There is just one problem: The filename doesn't match the one defined in the header. My code is:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$result['filename']."\""); #Here's the problem
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: private');
header('Content-Length: '.$result['size']);
```

but the file wont download as whatever `$result['filename']` is set to but the script name instead.

After renaming the .php to the correct extension it works fine but thats not convenient.

Comment: Where is the code which generates the `$result` array?

Comment: it's a simple mysqli query

Comment: Remove Content-Description. Remove Content-Transfer-Encoding. Set Content-Type to the actual media type. Remove most of the Cache-Control directives, unless you know what you're doing...

Comment: didn't help, type of a binary file is octet-stream (as far as i know) still downloads as file.php